# MV4 Routing Dynamic Routing from MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following sample data from a MySQL table.

[image: Sample data]

My question is in my MVC 4 project how can I get routing to work so that if a user goes to the URL www.mydomain.com/products/apples/ I want the call to actually be the view of www.mydomain.com/products/index/1, how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this one route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Product", "products/{productName}", 
    new {controller = "products", action="index"});
```

This route is saying:

> When a request comes in with a URL matching the pattern: "products/{productName}" (e.g. http://www.example.com/products/apple), pass that over to the "index" action in the "ProductsController" to handle and pass the segment of the url indicated by the {productName} placeholder, in to that action as the parameter called "productName".

Then your action would be:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string productName) {
    // Lookup product from DB

    // do stuff
    var viewModel = ...;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So, when a request comes in for products/apple, "apple" gets passed into the Index action as the productName parameter.

Comment: Can you expand the answer a bit more, as I'm new to MVC and struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in you `RouteConfig.cs` before the default route expression.

```
foreach (var item in _context.products)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        item.Url,
        "products/" + item.Url,
        new { controller = "products", action = "index", @id = item.ProductId }
    );
}
```

In above `_context.products` is used to retrieve the products from the DB. You can modify this according your models.

Comment: When is the code in RouteConfig.cs execute ?  Is when the application (IIS) starts or when a URL is requested ?  Also, this application will have in the region of 100,000 products so will there be any performance issue doing it this way.

Comment: This code will be run at the time of application start. So if you have so many records it will run slow at first time but after that wouldn't take time. If you don't want this either than you can use route constraint.

Comment: What is the recommended way of handling this many URLs.  Also, what about if a URL is added or changed once the application (IIS) has started.

Comment: If you choose route constraint than certainly it wouldn't take time initially but it will check the route every time when the specified URL being requested.